# Google Map Api with Search button

Tags: android

Hi i'm trying to implement google api in android. I got the map displayed.Now I want to implement the same with routes of 2 user given addresses. First of all i tried to display with a single text box  and a button. I am getting the following error in the logcat :

```
 01-28 07:14:29.500: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(827): Google Play Store is missing.
        01-28 07:14:29.550: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(827): Google Play Store is missing.
        01-28 07:14:29.550: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(827): Google Play Store is missing.
        01-28 07:14:29.590: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(827): Google Play Store is missing.
        01-28 07:14:29.590: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(827): Google Play Store is missing.
        01-28 07:14:29.670: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(827): Google Play Store is missing.
        01-28 07:14:29.690: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(827): Google Play Store is missing.
        01-28 07:14:30.030: I/Choreographer(827): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be                          doing too much work on its main thread.
        01-28 07:14:31.530: D/gralloc_goldfish(827): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
        01-28 07:10:03.846: I/Choreographer(827): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
        01-28 07:10:12.196: D/AndroidRuntime(827): Shutting down VM
        01-28 07:10:12.196: W/dalvikvm(827): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3aaeb90)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827): Process: com.example.locationgooglemap, PID: 827
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827): java.lang.NullPointerException
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
        01-28 07:10:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        01-28 07:10:12.296: D/dalvikvm(827): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 159K, 8% free 3122K/3364K, paused 35ms, total 47ms
```

Can anyone give me a solution? I am pretty new to Android and find it.little bit difficult.

Comment: Did u try this into Emulator?

Comment: Yes i tried it in emulator only. Also i tried in Android device but it says, "unfortunately your app has stopped"

Comment: you need to update your play services lib and try

Comment: I should update in my android device? in the logcat, it also shows nullpointerexception?

Comment: I tried with latest google play services. I am getting the same error message as "unfortunately your app has stopped"